# Video Playback Time not displaying

Tags: javascript, html

i am unable to get my video playback time to work i will list my code below, any help please? I tried using the code i entered below but i get "00:NaN" when i play the video. Here is my HTML below.

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="VideoControls">
<button type="button" id="PlayPause" >Play</button>
<button type="button" id="MuteUnmute" >Mute</button>
<p id="vidTime"></p> <input type="range" id ="seekBar" min=0 max=100 step=1 value=0> 
<p>5</p><input type="range" id="volControl" min=0 max=1 step=0.1 value=0.5>
<p id="curtime"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript below

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialiseWebPage);


function initialiseWebPage()
{       
const curtime = document.getElementById ("curtime");
myVideo.addEventListener ("timeupdate",displayVideoTime );  
}       

 function displayVideoTime()
 {
    let minutes = Math.floor(myVideo.currentTime / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor(myVideo.current % 60);
    if(minutes < 10)
    {
        minutes="0"+minutes;
    }
    if(seconds<10)
    {
        seconds="0"+seconds;
    }
      curtime.innerHTML = minutes+":"+seconds;      
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo : let seconds = Math.floor(myVideo.current % 60); It has to be let seconds = Math.floor(myVideo.currentTime % 60)